# PostgreSQL error when trying to connect from node application

Tags: node.js, postgresql, kubernetes, sequelize.js

```
FATAL: no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet
```

Logs from my postgreSQL instance in my kubernetes cluster when trying to connect to it by doing the following:

```
const { POSTGRES_DATABASE, POSTGRES_USERNAME, POSTGRES_PASSWORD } = require('../config/config');

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
    const conn = new Sequelize(POSTGRES_DATABASE, {
        username: POSTGRES_USERNAME,
        password: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
    });
```

config/config.js

```
    const config = {
        POSTGRES_DATABASE: 'postgres://postgres/postgresdb',
        POSTGRES_USERNAME: 'postgresadmin',
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'admin123',
        SERVER_PORT: '5000'
    }

module.exports = config;
```

I am using SequelizeJS in nodeJS.
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/

It seems like the requests are connecting alright due to seeing the attempts in the postgreSQL logs. However something goes wrong and I wonder if it's wrong with permissions in postgres or the node service.

Appreciate some help or ideas

Comment: is `POSTGRES_USERNAME` a variable? Where is it being defined?

Comment: I updated first post @doublesharp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630323/no-postgresql-user-name-specified-in-startup-packet could you refer that one?

Comment: I am not connecting with username / password in the URI. @PyaePhyoeShein

Comment: You are passing in the username for the password - `password: POSTGRES_USERNAME`

Comment: And not passing in the port

Comment: The default Postgres port is 5432. If you’re planning to use 5000, you need to pass that in to your connection. Right now you’re extracting 3/4 of your variables from your config and only using 2 of them. Also, what ip address is this server located? It’s going to expect the host to be localhost unless you tell it otherwise. If it’s on localhost then you’re fine, but if not then you should configure that as well.

Comment: @doublesharp port shouldn't be needed, the SERVER_PORT is meant for which port the node app should run on. I changed to POSTGRES_PASSWORD but still getting same error

Comment: Also, the database you’re using differs from the one in the configure. That’s seems odd.

Comment: postgres.default is the IP to the service. can be called with both .default and without. The thing is it reaches the postgres service, but still failing on FATAL no username thing

Comment: I guess my point is, either use the one from your config.js, or delete it from config.js. Adding it to config.js and not using it is confusing and will lead to more confusion later.

Comment: Agreed, Changed it.

Comment: @Nate the internal dns to the postgres is tcp://postgres

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Sequelize documentation that you linked, the args to creating a new connection are db, username, password. Your code did db, and then an object with username and password keys. This object is not correct and caused it to not find the username or password. Try this instead:

```
const { POSTGRES_DATABASE, POSTGRES_USERNAME, POSTGRES_PASSWORD } = require('../config/config');

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const conn = new Sequelize(POSTGRES_DATABASE, POSTGRES_USERNAME, POSTGRES_PASSWORD);
```

Sequelize *does* allow for an optional options object as the last argument, but the username and password are not expected to be in there.

This page of the documentation feels confusing to me.

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/usage.html

I believe what it says is that you either need to define everything in the object, or do the database, username, and password as separate arguments, but I don’t see it supporting database in the arguments and username / password in the object.

It seems like this should work as well:

```
const conn = new Sequelize({
  database: POSTGRES_DATABASE,
  username: POSTGRES_USERNAME,
  password: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
});
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, nice catch. 
Now I get Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
And it's not localhost I want to connect to, so I guess i'll need to define just the database name in the POSTGRES_DATABASE and then set a host somewhere in the options object

Comment: You need to add a`host` to the options object then.

Comment: I now realize that my last comment ran together. A “host” key is what you need to specify, for it to know the IP address or domain of the database. It looks like you’ll also want to set dialect to 'postgres'. I’m uncertain if Sequelize is aware that Postgres runs on port 5432 by default. You may need to specify that as the “port” option as well.

Comment: I'm currently doing dialect: 'postgres', host: 'postgres' but it seems it doesn't reach the postgres service now at all. it says port is based of dialect so shouldnt be needed. // custom port; default: dialect default

Comment: Is node running directly on your computer? If you’re running it in a Docker container or a Virtual Machine, you may be having a problem with DNS not being shared from your computer to the VM.

Comment: Also, silly question but it’s good to double check — Is the Postgres actually running?

Comment: No I have the node & postgres deployed in a kubernetes cluster and I know the internal DNS works due to having other services running and communicating between eachother.

Comment: Like you said it was a kubernetes issue at last. everything is running now with the changes you suggested! Thanks for all the help

Comment: Glad to hear it! No problem.